# Need help returning the input variable with an if statement

Tags: python, if-statement, input, var

I am new to stackoverflow and python, is it possible to return the utility function within the class type function and then sort it by the class input? Let me know if you have any suggestions or help. Thanks

```
rates = pd.read_csv('data')

CNP_TDSP= rates.loc[(rates['TDSP'] == 'CNP')]
TNMP_TDSP= rates.loc[(rates['TDSP'] == 'TNMP')]
AEPC_TDSP= rates.loc[(rates['TDSP'] == 'AEPC')]
AEPN_TDSP= rates.loc[(rates['TDSP'] == 'AEPN')]
ONC_TDSP= rates.loc[(rates['TDSP'] == 'ONC')]

TDSP_OPTIONS = ['CNP', 'TNMP', 'AEPC', 'AEPN', 'ONC']
print(TDSP_OPTIONS)

userInput = input('Enter tdsp:')
class_input = input('Enter class type:')


def utility():
    if userInput == 'CNP':
        display(CNP_TDSP)
    if userInput == 'TNMP':
        display(TNMP_TDSP) 
    if userInput == 'AEPC':
        display(AEPC_TDSP)
    if userInput == 'AEPN':
        display(AEPN_TDSP)
    if userInput == 'ONC':
        display(ONC_TDSP)        


utility()

def class_type():
    if class_input == 'Resi':
        display(utility['Class'] == 'Resi)

class_type()
```

> output: File "/tmp/ipykernel_28447/2787243890.py", line 37
> display(utility['Class'] == 'Resi) SyntaxError: EOL while scanning string literal

Comment: you are missing a closing quote after `'Resi` That's what is causing your error

Comment: def class_type():
    if class_input == 'Resi':
---> 37         display(utility['Class'] == 'Resi')
     38 
     39 

TypeError: 'function' object is not subscriptable
​

Answer (score 0):

```py
def class_type():
    if class_input == 'Resi':
        display(utility['Class'] == 'Resi)
```

Add a quote after 'Resi